# Can powerbi file be refreshed on a different computer?

Tags: refresh, powerbi

I need to refresh the dataset on a powerbi desktop file. The data source is an excel file placed on my onedrive for business folder - to which I have access to. I also saved my pbix file in the folder, however I am using a Mac as of the moment and the only way I'm thinking of is to share the pbix file from one drive to my colleague from work. Will that work, or is there any other way to refresh the data without connecting to the desktop file?

P.S. I've check the refresh, but since my work laptop is offline - I can't schedule a refresh

Answer (score 0):

In powerBI without sharing the pbix file you can share the dashboard with your colleagues just by selecting 'share' on the dashboard.
For the data source you can use an online database instead of the oneDrive file.

Answer (score 0):

The way to allow PowerBI to refresh data from your Onedrive for business is to "share" the file in Onedrive for business. https://medium.com/@Konstantinos_Ioannou/onedrive-powerbi-desktop-use-valid-paths-to-import-data-stored-in-onedrive-for-business-60089848e594#.e9wn6kqjn

Then you can share a) either the PBIX file (refresh will be enabled; authentication to the file is "oauth2"). Or you can upload it to the PowerBI web service and share the dashboard there. You need to reauthenticate the data source and then also scheduled refresh will work.

Comment: If you don't need the modelling capabilities of PowerBI desktop, you can also build the report in the web client of www.powerbi.com.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-get-data-from-files/

This will keep the powerBI report (on the web) automatically up to date, without exposing any data via a shared link.

In such a scenario you might want to check out, if you can model the data locally via Excel (Through Power Query) and save the resulting file always to Onedrive for Business; allowing the web based dashboard to be updated).

Answer (score 0):

I would publish your report to the PowerBi online service. Here you can then share the report with your colleague and setup a schedule refresh using the data gateway.

This would require a network connection though.